# Generate random numbers till Button click (UWP)

Tags: c#, random, uwp

I have a textblock and a button.

I want the textblock to be filled with a random number when I click the button and it should change the random number every 5 seconds. When I click the button a second time it should stop at the last random number.

How do I make this? This is what I tried:

```
    bool thisStatus = false;

    private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (thisStatus == false)
        {
            thisStatus = true;
        }
        else thisStatus = false;
        random();
    }

        private void random()
    {
        while (thisStatus)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int RandomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
            txtBlck.Text = RandomNumber.ToString();
            Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `thisStatus = !thisStatus` saves you 3 lines of code and makes it more clear.

Comment: First, `Task.Delay(5000)` on it's own won't actually cause a delay. You must `await` it. Change `private void random()` to `private async Task Random()` and await your delay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool thisStatus = false;

private async void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    thisStatus = !thisStatus // mke the toggling simple.
    await random();
}

private async Task random()
{
    while (thisStatus)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int RandomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
        txtBlck.Text = RandomNumber.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

> you need to await the task delay method because awaiting makes sure it completes before moving on.

Comment: `await random()` in void method?

Comment: worked. I had to change "private void bnt_click" to "private async void btn_click" though

Comment: yes thanks for the correction @axbeit I forgot to add async in button click but now I have updated the answer :)

Comment: @p3tch random is not returning void, it is returning a Task.

Comment: @touseefbsb yes but you were awaiting it in a method that wasn't marked as async. Doesn't matter now as you've edited your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [dispatcher Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Threading_DispatcherTimer_Start)

```
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);

int RandomNumber;
Random random = new Random();

private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (thisStatus == false)
    {
       thisStatus = true;
       dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
        else {
          thisStatus = false;
          dispatcherTimer.Stop();
         }
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RandomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
}
```